# Trying to find a user's manual for Blender 2.69

Tags: documentation

Is there a downloadable manual available for blender version 2.69? All searches I've tried do not yield a result for version 2.69.

Comment: According to the [Blender Index](https://download.blender.org/release/) Blender 2.93 was the last release before 3.0

Comment: As Emir said, there is no such version. Did you mean 2.76? For manuals since 2.79 you can access them through the version selection at the bottom left corner at https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/. The title page of each version contains a download of the HTML pages. More recent versions of the manual are also offered as an epub.

Comment: Oops, I meant 2.69.

Comment: Any particular reason why you're using 2.69? - The earliest online and downloadable manual is for 2.79 and is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/index.html). 2.69 was released almost 10 years ago (October 2013) so is way out of date!

Comment: Documentation for version 2.68 can be found [here](https://docs.blender.org/api/?C=M;O=A).

Comment: @tetii He asked for 2.69, but it's there too ;)